# Salmon turned green - is it safe to eat?

Tags: food-safety, refrigerator, salmon

I left a meal with salmon in the refrigerator for 3 days. The salmon skin is turning green.

Is it safe to consume it? If not, is it salvageable at all?

Comment: I don't see why this has been downvoted, it's a reasonable question with detail which could be useful to others. @nz_21, in general if food wasn't green to begin with in the fridge I wouldn't eat it, with a few exceptions.

Comment: What would the few exceptions be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would strongly recommend against consuming this fish.
In general you should cook fresh fish on the same day you bought it and not store cooked fish in the fridge for longer than a maximum of two days. Changes in colour, smell or texture are commonly a strong indicator that the fish has gone bad and eating it comes with a risk of a [scombroid food poisoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scombroid_food_poisoning).